# The images miss after I update a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I create a scaffold and trying to upload image with Active_Storage and AWS S3, it's successful for uploading images. However, the images are gone after I enter the "edit" page and click "update" and the terminal told that all the images were deleted, anyone knows how to fix it?
[edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl9xR.png) and [after clicking update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9U10.png)
This is the model and controller

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pictures

  def picture_as_thumbnail(pic)
    return unless pic.content_type.in?(%W[image/jpeg image/png])
    pic.variant(resize_to_limit: [200, 200]).processed
  end
end
```

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to product_url(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is terminal after ia click update

```
12:29:53 web.1  | Started PATCH "/products/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-19 12:29:53 +0800
12:29:53 web.1  | Processing by ProductsController#update as TURBO_STREAM
12:29:53 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product"=>{"name"=>" 123", "description"=>"123", "pictures"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"9"}
12:29:53 web.1  |   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `set_product'
12:29:53 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   Product Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products"."id" = ?  [["name", " 123"], ["updated_at", "2023-06-19 04:29:53.491920"], ["id", 9]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?  [["record_id", 9], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 114]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 115]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 116]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   Product Update (0.1ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", "2023-06-19 04:29:53.501292"], ["id", 9]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (12.4ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 114], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f2844044278 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/114>>
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 115], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f2844069ac8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/115>>
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 116], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f283c25e110 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/116>>
12:29:53 web.1  | Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/9
12:29:53 web.1  | Completed 302 Found in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 13.7ms | Allocations: 10652)
12:29:53 web.1  |
12:29:53 web.1  |
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 114], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f283c274758 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/114>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 114], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 114]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 42], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::VariantRecord"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 117]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."id" = ?  [["id", 42]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 114], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 114]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   TRANSACTION (19.6ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 117], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f283c102320 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/117>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 115], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f283c057e48 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/115>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 115], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 115]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 43], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::VariantRecord"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 118]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."id" = ?  [["id", 43]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 115], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 115]]
12:29:53 web.1  | Started GET "/products/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-19 12:29:53 +0800
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   TRANSACTION (12.8ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 118], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f27d7832970 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/118>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 116], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f27d7855268 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/116>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 116], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 116]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 44], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::VariantRecord"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."id" = ?  [["id", 119]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Destroy (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."id" = ?  [["id", 44]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 116], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 116]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   TRANSACTION (13.8ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 119], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f2844904fc0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/119>>
12:29:53 web.1  | Processing by ProductsController#show as TURBO_STREAM
12:29:53 web.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
12:29:53 web.1  |   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `set_product'
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendering products/show.html.erb within layouts/application
12:29:53 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?  [["record_id", 9], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"]]
12:29:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/products/_product.html.erb:12
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendered products/_product.html.erb (Duration: 3.0ms | Allocations: 1068)
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.9ms | Allocations: 1686)
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 117], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f28459c38c0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/117>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 117], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 117]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 117], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 117]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   TRANSACTION (13.4ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendered /home/cc/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/hotwire-livereload-1.2.3/app/views/hotwire/livereload/_head_action_cable.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 738)
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 8)
12:29:53 web.1  |   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 58.1ms | Allocations: 18951)
12:29:53 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 60.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 19894)
12:29:53 web.1  |
12:29:53 web.1  |
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 118], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f283c1e30c8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/118>>
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 118], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 118]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 118], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 118]]
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   TRANSACTION (14.0ms)  commit transaction
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   S3 Storage (379.9ms) Deleted file from key: ybi88vnlp6prj2j7kxhkbh86da11
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   S3 Storage (359.6ms) Deleted file from key: 4vkiyyuj98xdrayul8li1xjey1ue
12:29:53 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   S3 Storage (308.0ms) Deleted file from key: n0hplu1t8id2olzuo6xfy2cm5xzq
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   S3 Storage (302.4ms) Deleted file from key: nnadu43xtf3k4mqrbe53oa8bj9yy
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721]   S3 Storage (81.4ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/ybi88vnlp6prj2j7kxhkbh86da11/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 6bb95756-b75d-4e6f-b24f-3ed1b17b2721) from Async(default) in 505.91ms
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 119], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352] Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352) from Async(default) enqueued at 2023-06-19T04:29:53Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f27d7839ab8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://your-cool-app/ActiveStorage::Blob/119>>
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 119], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ?  [["blob_id", 119]]
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 119], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ?  [["id", 119]]
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   TRANSACTION (15.0ms)  commit transaction
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b]   S3 Storage (93.1ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/4vkiyyuj98xdrayul8li1xjey1ue/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb]   S3 Storage (88.4ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/n0hplu1t8id2olzuo6xfy2cm5xzq/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: be9b3033-8e3b-43ae-8c61-fe05889b6e6b) from Async(default) in 495.55ms
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 24396ba7-0367-457d-a9d6-a0320da253bb) from Async(default) in 452.02ms
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1]   S3 Storage (78.5ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/nnadu43xtf3k4mqrbe53oa8bj9yy/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: ef5b8011-f98d-484b-88c6-11c6567ef8b1) from Async(default) in 414.11ms
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   S3 Storage (337.4ms) Deleted file from key: vs4441uwul8gqmd2yzg7lmiwissv
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   S3 Storage (84.2ms) Deleted file from key: fjgyu2bpnghwpuah4j806s9f0tik
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1]   S3 Storage (77.8ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/vs4441uwul8gqmd2yzg7lmiwissv/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: 398c43df-6c08-4a1a-bdb2-ff2de3c07ef1) from Async(default) in 482.7ms
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352]   S3 Storage (77.7ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/fjgyu2bpnghwpuah4j806s9f0tik/
12:29:54 web.1  | [ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352] Performed ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: c7ce24e2-bbbc-4134-a932-07d61b1aa352) from Async(default) in 499.73ms
```

Comment: simply restring pictures from getting update. use below
`if @product.update(product_params.except(:pictures))`

You can also make changes in edit form to prevent this.

Comment: @AmolMohite do I put this line in "update" method in products controller?

Comment: yes add this in update action.
And also add your form code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass empty array as param `"pictures"=>[""]`. That's why you delete all the pictures (replace with empty collection)

You can choose one of the options:

- use [hidden fields](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35817#issuecomment-484158884) for existing attachments in the view

```
<% if @product.pictures.attached? %>
  <% @product.pictures.each do |ph| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :pictures, multiple: true, value: ph.signed_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

- prevent overwrite attachments by update [in config](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-storage-replace-on-assign-to-many)

```rb
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

Comment: wondering why "pictures"=>[""] overwrite the origianl pictures? I mean what makes "pictures"=>[""] happen exactly?

Comment: do you mean like this ?
```ruby
<%= form.label :pictures %>
    <%= form.file_field :pictures, multiple: true %>
    <% product.pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.picture_as_thumbnail(picture)), picture %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you mean replace that with 
`<% if @product.pictures.attached? %>
  <% @product.pictures.each do |ph| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :pictures, multiple: true, value: ph.signed_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>`

Comment: But why hidden field can prevent pictures from being overwitten?

Comment: I got this ```undefined method `hidden_field' for #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 120, name: "pictures", record_type: "Product", record_id: 9, blob_id: 120, created_at: "2023-06-19 05:38:37.811339000 +0000">``` instead...

Comment: I works!! One last question, base on those two solutions you provided, which is better?

Comment: There are two more things I would likt to asks
1 I want show the pictures I want uploading in the editing page not just the pictures attached, what can I do ?

2. Everytime I click "choose pictures" and choose some pictures it will clean those I have chosen and upload the new one. I want it be more like "add pictures" not "choose again", can I do that?

Comment: sorry for not being specific, I mean in edit page will show all pictures attached already. And when I click "choose file" and select some picture there will be the file name next to the "choose file" button. However, if I click the button and select different pictures the previously selected pictures will be replace with most recently selected pictures. What I want to do is remaining the old selected pictures and add new selected not replaceing all of them, thanks.

Comment: It works. But what I want to do is add a upload button to preview the pictures before actually update the post. So I can even remove the picture at editing stage. How can I do it? thanks.

Comment: Create new question